# Apache Referer validation not working

Tags: apache

I want to allow request from some specific refers only. Below is my configuration.

```
RewriteCond "%{HTTP_REFERER}" "!^$"
RewriteCond "%{HTTP_REFERER}" "!test\.abc\.com/" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond "%{HTTP_REFERER}" "!www\.agent\.com/booking/" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond "%{HTTP_REFERER}" "!www.google.co.in/" [NC,OR]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.safar.com/jsp/session_expiry.jsp
```

But my configuration is not working. Apache is still forwarding the request to tomcat with response code 200. Please suggest what I am doing wrong? My apache version is 2.4.6. Same rule is working fine for apache 2.4.4.

Comment: Remove the double quotes around the URLs!

Comment: Same issue after removing double quotes. I am facing issue with apache 2.4.6.